# Photoshop enable Multiple undo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, undo

I'm used to applications allowing you to perform multiple undos at once with Ctrl-Z. I've found that at least the default setting in photoshop is only a single undo. How do i change this (im a photoshop newbie)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use photoshop 7 but should be similar in any later versions.

Edit>Preferences>General

Redoc Key - by default is Ctrl+Z (Toggles Undo/Redo)

Change it to Ctrl+Shift+z or something, and change the history states to a nice high value (I have 200).

Press Ok and jobs a good-un!

Comment: Hado to go hunting for some of the settings but i found them. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, *had to*...

Answer (score 5):

***You probably do not want to change this.***

Photoshop has a "**Step backward**" function that can be accessed by **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>**.

Also, you can step forward again by using **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>**.

Comment: In my eyes Photoshop not using the default undo key is a definite fail. Why not change it?

Comment: +1 In CS6 this is found in `Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts` and the "Step backwards/forwards" defaults are the opposite of your answer

Comment: My fingers got cancer after working with photoshops default settings... tell me just a single reason why not to change it @Aron Rotteveel

Answer (score 5):

In Photoshop CS3 you go **Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts**

Here you can change/add keyboard shortcuts to most Photoshop menu items, palette menus and tools.

Simply choose the **Edit** accordion section and click on the **Step Backwards** shortcut and click **Ctrl-Z**.
It might throw a warning as it is will be overwriting the Undo/Redo button, but don't worry about that.

Now you have it set up the way it should be.

Answer (score 3):

By default, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to go backward through the last undo states one-by-one.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to go forward.

Answer (score 1):

To change the number of undos in Photoshop, follow these steps:

Open Photoshop and go to the "Edit" menu at the top of the screen.

From the dropdown menu, select "Preferences" and then choose "Performance."

In the Performance preferences, you'll find a section titled "History & Cache." Look for the "History States" option.

Adjust the value next to "History States" to set the number of undos you want. Photoshop allows you to choose a number between 1 and 1000, but keep in mind that higher values may require more system resources.

Once you've set your desired number of undos, click "OK" to save the changes.

After changing the "History States" setting, you'll be able to use Ctrl-Z (or Command-Z on a Mac) to perform multiple undos up to the number you specified. If you exceed the limit, Photoshop will start removing the oldest history states as you continue undoing.

Remember that increasing the number of undos will consume more memory, so it's essential to find a balance between the number of undos you need and the available resources on your computer.