# Photoshop enable continuous undo

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop

A lot of programs will do continuous undo while the undo key is held down - MS Word for example, will keep undoing while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is being held. Photoshop seems to offer ["multiple undo"](https://superuser.com/questions/19878/photoshop-enable-multiple-undo), but if I'm understanding that post correctly, seems to mean "undo x steps with a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keypress" - which is not what I want. I want to keep undoing while I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> instead of spamming <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, just like in other programs such as MS Word.

Is there a way to get Photoshop to behave that way?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could just click in the History timeline, as many steps as you need.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is indeed one way that I have used when I needed mass undos, but I'm still interested to learn if there is a way to make Photoshop behave the same as other programs regarding continuous undo.

Comment: Not a function I've ever wanted before - but I tried it & it works for me here. Your linked question is from an old version of Ps when they had a toggle to undo/redo. I think they removed that as a default quite a few years ago… can't remember how long ago.

Comment: Ah, it is still switchable. I did a set & forget on this years ago. From the link - "In CS6 this is found in Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts…" It's now called legacy undo. Mine is off.

Comment: @Tetsujin I turned on "Use Legacy Undo Shortcuts" and switched the shortcuts for "Undo/Redo" and "Step Backward", but to no avail - it still won't let me hold down Ctrl+Z to undo.

Comment: You'll probably have to ask Adobe then.